# Is it possible to run queries on a SQLite DB that's in a OneDrive folder?

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app, onedrive

I have a "notes" app I'm working on and all of the user's notes are saved in a sqlite.db file. However, I would like this database file to be synchronized to the user's OneDrive cloud account so that the notes are up-to-date in the cloud. Eventually I will make the app compatible with Windows Phone and so the PC and Phone versions will stay synchronized through the OneDrive account.... if that even works out.

So I would like to know if it is possible to run queries on the sqlite.db file that's on the user's OneDrive account, or would I just have to re-sync the entire file every time there are changes in one location?

I could imagine that the latter approach would be a problem because I would need to know which individual records were modified or deleted and make changes accordingly, so yeah.... Help? :]

Answer (score 1):

> If it is possible to run queries on the sqlite.db file that's on the user's OneDrive account?

SQLite is not directly comparable to client/server SQL database engines such as  SQL Server or MySQL. It strives to provide **local data storage** for individual applications and devices. So you can't run queries on the sqlite.db file that's on the user's OneDrive account directly. If you want to work with user's OneDrive cloud account, you can take advantage of [OneDrive's App Folder](https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/appfolder.htm). However when you use this approach, you have to download and upload your SQLite DB file over and over for synchronizing data and as you can imagine, this would be complicated when dealing with network issues and conflicts.

According to your scenario, I'd suggest you use [Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/).

> When your app is in offline mode, users can still create and modify data, which will be saved to a local store. When the app is back online, it can synchronize local changes with your Azure Mobile App backend. The feature also includes support for detecting conflicts when the same record is changed on both the client and the backend. Conflicts can then be handled either on the server or the client.
>
> Offline sync has a number of benefits:
>
> - Improve app responsiveness by caching server data locally on the device
> - Create robust apps that remain useful when there are network issues
> - Allow end-users to create and modify data even when there is no network access, supporting scenarios with little or no connectivity
> - Sync data across multiple devices and detect conflicts when the same record is modified by two devices
> - Limit network use on high-latency or metered networks

For more info, please refer to [Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/), [Enable offline sync for your Windows app](http://Enable%20offline%20sync%20for%20your%20Windows%20app), and the [Todo offline sample](https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/TodoOffline/WindowsUniversal) in GitHub.